# How to freeze tableView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, tableview

I would like to freeze tableView, so user cant click on it, send signals to it etc.
The reason for this is becouse i control this tableView with another object, but in some situations i want to disable this connection between them.

`ui->lettersView->blockSignals(true)` emits signals anyway.

Comment: Doesn't `ui->lettersView->setEnabled(false);` work?

Comment: Since the signature is `bool QObject::blockSignals(bool block)`, does it returns true?

Comment: @vahancho setEnabled freezes object but it receives still signals.

Comment: @ABCplus yes, it does return true, its really strange

Comment: @MartinKóňa, which signals? How do you know that? Receives signals or emits them?

Comment: Try to monitor `QObject::signalsBlocked()` in your code, it should go back to `true` somewhere. E.g. check it after `blockSignals` and later..

Comment: @vahancho i have tableView in which i emit 'selectionChanged()' signal...i want to disable this emit just for the moment when the tableView gains QEvent::FocusIn.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to disconnect and then connect the signals. Not the better approach since `QObject::signalsBlocked()` should do its work, but...

Comment: If you want to disable just that signals then `disconnect` is the better approach since `QObject::blockSignals` blocks all the signals from that object.

Comment: @ABCplus yeah funny thing, i set blockSignals(true) and in slot i print signalsblocked :D so basically, i disable signals but it emis them, even calls connected slot

Comment: Interesting funtion would be opposite of 'emit()" funtion, when for example you gain focus on table...no signals are emitted but by pressing keys u can emit signals again

Comment: Could you provide your code? For example, put it to a cloud. I've never seen as `blockSignals` fails.

Comment: @Ezee i will try create some example to simulate this situation

Comment: @ABCplus disconnect/connect works for me fine. thanks for help